# Too many projects depending on a single parent pom.xml has negative side-effects

Tags: maven

We have about 45 java projects (two front-end applications, twenty back-end, and rest are common libraries) using a single parent `pom.xml`.

I upgraded one project's dependency to the latest version which required code changes in several places and non-trivial investigation of now failing tests. Instead of bumping up the dependency version in the parent `pom`, I updated the project's `pom` by overriding of the dependency version number.

This is not consistent as all dependency versions are specified in the parent `pom` using `<dependencyManagement>` with exception of this one case here. However, I am not ready to bump up the version for all projects and cause compilation errors.

I am tempted to bump up the version of the parent `pom`, bump up the library version there, and reference this new `pom` version from the single project. This means that there would be two active `poms` utilized by our projects to maintain and I do not like that.

What would be a better solution?

Comment: I would never define versions of libraries as dependencies. Always define them in dependencyManagement instead apart from being powermock a smell from my point of view...If you have defined it via dependencyManagement each project can simply decided to upgrade or not..furthermore a parent has a version so you can already release a new parent pom and you can migrate one project after another ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I set up the parent pom with the `<dependencyManagement>` already, thank you for bringing it up. Right, I agree with you, use of powermock points to other issues in the code base. Your response inspired me to upgrade the version in the parent pom and then downgrade individual objects.  This approach allows for the parent pom to maintain list of the latest versions and moves the burden of upgrade down to the individual projects.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the version in the parent `pom` and downgrade individual projects which cannot be upgraded without a considerable work. This approach allows for the parent pom to maintain list of the latest versions, it can continue moving forward, and the burden of upgrading is moved down to the individual projects.

Answer (score 0):

If the projects will not share the same classpath in the end, you can have a maven BOM (separate project, versioned) and import them into the projects that you need. Leave the parent pom on *how* to build the projects, but use the BOM for *what* to build. Your projects can then drift slightly of what libs they use, but you can manage each one and upgrade as you have time.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html